# No desktop environment

Tags: unity, ubuntu-gnome

I installed gnome 3 on my ubuntu 14.04. I did nor like it, so i removed gnome-shell and ubuntu-gnome-desktop. But now unity icon does not show up on login bar. It takes password, but returns to login screen again. Can anyone tell me what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, try reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop (unity):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```